# Runtime pointer-exception while copying one array to another inside a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The main goal is to copy an array in the constructor from the `main()` function. Using `cin >>` would be really easily, but I have to give the constructor an already defined array. I don't get any errors when compiling the program. Only during runtime it fails with this exception:

> Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. this->A was
>   0x1110112.

I've already tried to define these arrays in the class, even though I know this is not a good practice. But I can't do that as it will cause errors with pointers in another functions defined in this class. Here's what I got so far:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#define size 5
using namespace std;
class Matr
{
private:
    //const int size = 5;
    double **A;
    double *B;
public:
    Matr(double (*a)[size], double b[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                A[i][j] = a[i][j]; //here exception falls
            }
            B[i] = b[i];
        }
    }
};
int main()
{ 
    double A[5][5] = {              {-6,18,15,8,6},
                    {2,11,-18,17,23},
                    {-13,-2,8,-10,-5},
                    {1,13,11,-10,-5},
                    {10,21,8,-1,11} };
    double B[5] = { 0,-8,1,-2,-6 };
    Matr matr(A,B); //define the arrays
}
```

I would like to define this to arrays in the class for using them in the other functions. Is this even possible at all? :D

Comment: `A` is not initialized when you are assigning to it. It's just a plain pointer, it doesn't have any memory assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Matr` constructor, you should allocate memory for `A` and `B` using `new`.